# how to take android browser offline when my external ip changes?

Tags: browser, proxy, termux

My ISP only provides ipv4 ips dynamically. I have tracked them using a termux script and found that i can get back ips after reconnecting a couple of times.
Now what I want is to restrict my browser to a certain format of ips.

My idea:
Running a local simple proxy in termux and browsing through that. Whenever the connection gets lost, a script will shut the proxy and check the new external ip. will only restart the proxy when the format matches.

Now I am trying to figure out how to run a script whenever my data connection is lost ?

Please help me with your ideas regarding this or anything related to my main question. Thanks

Comment: Run a background service that executes `curl checkip.amazonaws.com` every few seconds.

Comment: but how do i pause a proxy. Can it be done using tinyproxy on android ?